# Im trying to deploy contract on Polygon Mumbai but cant

Tags: hardhat, polygon, alchemy

I get this error when deploying my contract. It only takes 3,600,000 gas to deploy and mumbai gas limit is 20,000,000.

```
deploying "DeqityFactory"exceeds block gas limit {"name":"ProviderError","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true} ProviderError: exceeds block gas limit
at HttpProvider.request (C:\Users\ptrma\learningWeb3\deqity-core\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:78:19)
at LocalAccountsProvider.request (C:\Users\ptrma\learningWeb3\deqity-core\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\accounts.ts:182:36)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. If your deploy script's (in hardhat-deploy atleast) gas limit is higher than the network's block gas limit then you will receive that error.